# The “rock cycle” of an Alderson Disk

Tags: metals, tectonics, erosion

In my world, human civilization would live on an Alderson Disk.

> An Alderson disk (named after Dan Alderson, its originator) is a hypothetical artificial astronomical megastructure, like Larry Niven's Ringworld and the Dyson sphere. The disk is a giant platter with a thickness of several thousand miles. The Sun rests in the hole at the center of the disk. The outer perimeter of an Alderson disk would be roughly equivalent to the orbit of Mars or Jupiter. According to the proposal, a sufficiently large disk would have a larger mass than its Sun. ([Source and additional info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alderson_disk))

In short, it is like a giant DVD with sun as it’s center. The outer perimeter of it will be equal to the orbit of the Jupiter. It is a giant megastructure that can be home for quadrillion of peoples and aliens.

The disk will be constructed using asteroids and will therefore be rich in metals and nutrients.

It seems to me that an Alderson Disk will have no volcanism or tectonic movement, therefore no mountain building and, above all, no [rock cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_cycle).

> The rock cycle is a basic concept in geology that describes transitions through geologic time among the three main rock types: sedimentary, metamorphic, and igneous. Each rock type is altered when it is forced out of its equilibrium conditions. For example, an igneous rock such as basalt may break down and dissolve when exposed to the atmosphere, or melt as it is subducted under a continent. Due to the driving forces of the rock cycle, plate tectonics and the water cycle, rocks do not remain in equilibrium and change as they encounter new environments. The rock cycle explains how the three rock types are related to each other, and how processes change from one type to another over time. This cyclical aspect makes rock change a geologic cycle and, on planets containing life, a biogeochemical cycle.

**The question:** Can an Alderson Disk have either a natural or artificial [rock cycle](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/rock-cycle/)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As you can read in our [help], we prefer to answer 1 question per post, while you are asking 3 at the moment.

Comment: I'm going to be that guy and say: proper grammar and syntax contributes greatly to reader understanding.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Please make your question self-contained. What is an Alderson Disc and what are the important features?

Comment: After seeing edits, I believe I understand your question and have edited it to be clear and to ask a specific question. As such, I've voted to reopen the question. If I have misunderstood your question, please let me know ASAP. (@L.Dutch, what do you think?)

Comment: Of course it can have an artificial rock cycle, if you want it to. I don't see why they would do it, but the incredibly rich and powerful inhabitants can always build gigantic machines to dig up the rocks, heat them up, subject them to massive pressure, oxidize them, hydrate them, and so on. On the other hand, the entire disc is an artificial construction, so that there can be nothing natural about a rock cycle.

Comment: @AlexP I believe Cubelite wanted to write that the disc was a natural construct, deviating from the usual definition of an Alderson disk. That being said, the wikipedia did mention that it was a great way to build a magical world upon the area so if there are massive ancient magical constructs that had created a cycle that was useable then it might help things.

Comment: @HarryMu: It cannot be a natural object. If it were a natural object, gravity would quickly re-arrange into a sphere. Something un-natural is keeping it from collapsing under its own gravity and something must be actively keeping the sun in the center of the disc.

Comment: The alderson disk is not an natural object. It’s made by an ancient human civilization. That civilization destroyed itself and the humans on the disk are the last survivors of that civilization.

Comment: The disk requires active upkeep at all times--if the systems fail the disk is lost as the strength required to keep it in existence far exceeds the strongest materials.  Thus you have active systems that can do whatever you want with the rock cycle.  Civilization might have fallen but the systems maintaining the disk have not.

Comment: "THE ALDERSON DISK IS UNSTABLE!"

Comment: The primary problem with that disk is that its mass center is located at the Sun's position, thus it should have artificial gravity throughout the inhabited portions of it, otherwise everything on its surface would gladly fall down to the Sun. And your disk does not seem to have anything like that.

Comment: Ugh!  What would gravity be like on a thing like that? All over the place, I imagine! Maybe that will give you your tectonics/rock cycles somehow?

Answer (score 2):

"It seems to me that an Alderson Disk will have no volcanism or tectonic movement"

Well... why does it seem that way to you?

An Alderson disk is not a natural object, and it certainly could be constructed as a rigid, solid object with no internal dynamics... but in order to have Earthlike gravity, it would have to be several thousand miles thick, and could easily support internal fluid layers just like a ball-shaped planet. Convection in the interior would thus produce plate motion and volcanism just like it does on Earth.

That would complicate the delicate balancing act necessary to keep the whole structure from collapsing, though, so there's certainly good reason to intentionally build it as a cold, solid structure. In that case, the rock cycle would have to be handled artificially, much like it is on Niven's Ringworld--some mechanism dredges sediment from seabeds and redeposits it at the tops of mountains, with the weight of new sediment at the top crushing lower levels back into rock. And you would probably want such a system as part of the larger mass redistribution system that keeps the disk in balance anyway.

Comment: How much weight will it need to crush the lower levels into rock?

Comment: @Cubelite: It is not clear what you mean by "lower levels" of the rock. The main gravitational force will be towards the center of the disk, parallel with the surface. The actual lower levels of the rock are situated towards the center of the disc, being crushed by the rock situated outwards from the center.

Comment: The gravitational force will be just like earth, pulling you down to the middle of the disk. It could be done by aritfical gravity making. I would like to know how much weight of new sediment at the top is need to crush lower levels back into rock.

Comment: @AlexP Not when you include the centrifugal component. Over most of an Alderson disk, the surface can be well-approximated as an infinite plane, and gravity points mostly perpendicular to the surface. The remaining components can be cancelled by spin if the disk has an appropriate radial mass distribution. It's not a *stable* equilibrium... but that's why you have machinery to maintain it.

Comment: @Cubelite Depends on the type of sediment, but generally... not much. Tens to hundreds of tons of pressure may sound like a lot, but dirt is heavy, and just a few meters of it will start to compact. If your disk has mountains and seas like Earth, it will form sedimentary rocks like Earth.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Is that a rock cycle? Although, I am not sure how much temperature is need for it to be melted into magma.

Comment: @Cubelite It's a cycle, and it involves rocks. The fact that it's a mechanical-chemical cycle without any thermal components just means that it's not like Earth's rock cycle, not that isn't a cycle.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley a mechanical-chemical cycle? How does it work?

Comment: @Cubelite Rocks get chemically and mechanically weathered, and turn into sediment. The sediment gets mechanically squished back together, and chemically bonds over time. Then it gets weathered again. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley What will happen to minerals like coal and iron and human products like steel?

Comment: @Cubelite The same thing that happens to them on Earth. Unless it burns, nothing much happens to coal. If it does burn, it becomes CO2, which might later be integrated into rocks as carbonates, which can be useful for cementing other sediments together. Iron and steel rust, and may end up redeposited as hematite or magnetite and incorporated into other rocks.